# SQL Aggregate Count Function and ORDER BY Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS Access Database table, which has the following columns, amongst other columns: Product and State - the table is named "Consumer_Complaints". Complaints are made on a number of products in all the US states. I have written the following SQL query to obtain a list of all products, grouped by state (this query is the first step to writing another query to obtain the product that received the most number of complaints in each state):

```
SELECT State, Product
FROM Consumer_Complaints
ORDER BY State, Product;
```

The query above works.

However, I don't know why the following query to compute the number of each kind of product, grouped by state, does not work (this query is the second step to writing the query to obtain the product that received the most number of complaints in each state):

```
SELECT State, Product, COUNT(Product) AS Product_Count
FROM(SELECT State, Product
FROM Consumer_Complaints
ORDER BY State, Product)
ORDER BY State, Product;
```

I get the following error message from MS Access: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'State' as part of an aggregate function."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Simplify, simplify.

```
SELECT State, Product, COUNT(Product) AS Product_Count 
FROM Consumer_Complaints 
GROUP BY State, Product
ORDER BY State, Product;
```

I don't know why you got the error message "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'State' as part of an aggregate function." It's a little nonsensical.

But when you use an aggregate function like COUNT(), MAX(), SUM(), etc, you also need use a GROUP BY clause. And, speaking a little loosely, every column that's in the SELECT clause must be either a) the argument to an aggregate function, or b) named in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score -1):

it should be like this:

```
SELECT  State,
        Product,
        COUNT(Product) AS Product_Count
FROM    Consumer_Complaints
GROUP BY State,
        Product
ORDER BY State,
        Product;
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need of subquery Just use this query

```
SELECT State, Product, COUNT(Product) AS Product_Count
FROM
Consumer_Complaints
GROUP BY State, Product
ORDER BY State, Product;
```

If your requirement is to use only sub query then You can use this

```
SELECT State, Product, COUNT(Product) AS Product_Count
FROM
( 
SELECT State, Product
FROM Consumer_Complaints
)
GROUP BY State, Product
ORDER BY State, Product;
```

You did not have to use `ORDER BY State, Product` in `subquery` Coz you have already write that in the outer query.

Comment: If anyone thinks that I am wrong then Please comment that what is wrong in my query.